# Class of ID Change based on URL - URL Based Image Swap -

Tags: javascript, css, url, if-statement

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Based on URL (ie., foo.com/item1), the div element "logoswap" receives a different class.

The following is the code I put together but it seems completely wrong. I'm not a JS pro by any means, XHTML/CSS is more my speed (some PHP)... I cannot use PHP, even if it is possible in PHP (and I know it is because I have a PHP version of what I need done already, but I can't call the PHP properly.

I'm really just trying to get a different logo to show up based on the directory/url... It doesn't have to be a background element called in by the CSS class necessarily, I just need a different image to load based on the aforementioned url variable...

```
  $(function() {
  var url = location.pathname;

  if(url.indexOf('item1') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("logoswap").className += " class1";
   }

  elseif(url.indexOf('item2') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("logoswap").className += "class2";
   }

  elseif(url.indexOf('item3') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("logoswap").className += "class3";
   }

  elseif(url.indexOf('item4') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("logoswap").className += "class4";
   }

  elseif(url.indexOf('item5') > -1) {
    document.getElementById("logoswap").className += "class5";
   }

  else {
    document.getElementById("logoswap").className += "class1";
   }

  });
```

That's what I have... Ugly I'm sure.

That's why I'm here though, I definitely need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assigning CSS Class By URL Pathname

> A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B347f/) has been setup for
>   this solution.

Here is a case for using numeric expressions if they are available. This does not apply to the above question.

```
$(function() {
  var rgx = /item(\d+)$/,
      url = location.pathname,
      id = (rgx.test(url)) ? url.match(rgx)[1] : '1';
  $("#logoswap").addClass("class" + id);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

In light of the new details you may need an array of values, these should be derived from or exactly equal to the class names you intend to use.

```
$(function(){
  // my favorite way to make string arrays.
  var matches = "brand1 brand2 brand3".split(" "),
      url = location.pathname.match(/\w+$/)[0], // get the last item
      id = matches.indexOf(url),
      className = matches[(id > -1) ? id : 0];
  $("#logoswap").addClass(className);
});
```

To make this work you will need a few things in place. I will assume that the paths will end in a number as we have outlined here. The default ends with `1`. You will need the images to be accessible. You need to define the styles for each possibility.

---

### CSS Setup

```
#logoswap {
  height : 200px;
  width : 200px;
}
.class1 {
  background-image : url(/path/to/default.jpg);
}
.class2 {
  background-image : url(/path/to/second.jpg);
}
.brand1 {
  background-image : url(/path/to/brand/1/logo.jpg);
}
...
```

---

### Without jQuery

if you do not have jQuery in your code you may need to use `window.onload`.

```
(function(){
  var old = window.onload;
  window.onload = function(){
    old();
    var r = /item(\d+)$/,
        url = location.pathname,
        id = (r.test(url)) ? url.match(r)[1] : '1';
    document.getElementById('logoswap').className += "class" + id;
  };
})()
```

> I just want to take a moment here to
>   encourage anyone who is doing this
>   type of code to get used to Regular
>   Expressions and learn them. They are
>   far and away the most frequently used
>   cross language part of my development
>   arsenal.

Comment: I can't release the full code - and since this is not implemented yet (just sandboxing on our dev), let's just say for the sake of argument that the only content is the <DIV> I need to have the class change on.

Comment: Sorry - I know it seems like a vague kind of jerk-ish response, let me see if I can't put something together as an HTML visual.

Comment: Nothing wrong with closed source my friend. Did this get any further along? I guess the answer may be to verify that the class declarations exist and that the images exist according to those style declarations. I will run a quick jsFiddle up to ensure that the above code works. Also maybe you can indicate what type of behavior you are getting. Also I notice you are using the jQuery notation for document ready. Are you loading the jQuery library?

Comment: I may have mis-read the question. Are you saying your current code doesn't work?

Comment: The JQuery library is being loaded up from Google, perhaps I should drop the JQuery notation and just go "old school"?

Comment: @Ash - That is partially what I'm saying. The other part was making sure I have coded this properly.

Comment: @RyanAtONeal No, if you are using the jQuery library, use it fully. The dom selection notation is much more terse and declarative. So if the top code does not work, please describe what behavior you are getting vs. what you are expecting.

Comment: I would need to define an array for this correct? I'm really not that great at this sorry

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that those item1, item2, etc. were placeholders for an example of the code. That's my fault.

The directories will be our brand names "ONEAL-MOTO", "BLUR-OPTICS", etc... I don't know how much that effects the code. I've been away from Stack in a short meeting and didn't see you've been going to town.

Comment: I really do appreciate your help and level of knowledge/skill

Comment: Thank you for all your work here... I'm going to implement what you've shown and I'll be back if it doesn't work for me, I can't imagine why not.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that wrong with what you have. You could tidy it up with something like below.

```
$(function() {
    var url = location.pathname;
    var logo = document.getElementById("logoswap");
    var i = 6;

    logo.className = "class1";

    while(i--)
    {
        if(url.indexOf("item" + i) > -1) {
            logo.className = "class" + i;
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using just HTML/CSS, you could add (or append via javascript) an `id` to the `body` of the page:

```
<body id="item1">
```

Then in your CSS, create a selector:

```
#item1 #logoswap {
    // class1 CSS
}
```

Comment: I would be able to do this if my pages weren't dynamically generated, meaning I can't access "directly" the individual pages that need to call-up these class changes.