# Change body by if else statement - url

Tags: javascript, if-statement, getelementbyid

If url is subdomain http://one.example.com/dsnknw?211218 then show div one, if http://two.example.com/ppppnw?201218 than show div two.

Each body has background image

```
<style>
#siteone {
background: url(http://example.info/backgroundone.PNG); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    }
#sitetwo {
    background: url(http://example.info/backgroundtwo.PNG); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    }
</style>
```

and a link associated:

```
<div id="one">
<a id="link1" href="https://click.com" target="_top"></a>
</div>

<div id="two">
<a id="link2" href="https://click2.com" target="_top"></a>
</div>
```

I have tried a few codes including

```
document.getElementById("body")
```

[Class of ID Change based on URL - URL Based Image Swap -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942722/class-of-id-change-based-on-url-url-based-image-swap)
[Creating Conditional Statement Based On Page URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727856/creating-conditional-statement-based-on-page-url)
ETC

Comment: Why not put a class on each of your pages body, and make different css rules for each body.otherClass?  Then no need for javascript at all.

Comment: There's [only one body per document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Sectioning_root). You should reword your question taking that into account. `document.getElementById("body")` doesn't make sense because you didn't set the id of anything to "body". You probably meant `document.querySelector("body")`, or even better, `document.body`. Your question should show what you tried, actual vs. expected behavior error messages. Best thing would be to create a simple reproducible example

Comment: The whole issue for me is the background. It only displays properly in body and not div

Answer (score 1):

Based on Juan's comment, two body tags isn't a viable approach for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Sectioning_root. You should make use of parent wrappers instead.

```
<div class="parent">
<a id="link2" href="https://click.com" target="_top"></a>
</div>
```

Using `window.location` will help you parse the current URL so you can properly do what you need.

What I would do is query the element that has href attribute of `window.location.href` and then get the `.parentElement` to get the direct parent.

```
const url = window.location.href;
const targetParent = document.querySelector('.parent a[href="' + url + '"]').parentElement;

targetBody.style.display = "block";
```

This will not work if `<a>` is located somewhere deeper. That being the case I would say add another attribute for the parent so we can directly query it.

```
<div class="parent" url="https://click.com">
<a id="link2" href="https://click.com" target="_top"></a>
</div>
```

then

```
const url = window.location.href;
const targetParent = document.querySelector('.parent[url="' + url + '"]').parentElement;
```

If your url has other extra strings like `http://click.com?id=foobar` then this will also not work. You would have to manually concatenate other properties from `window.location` so you can only get what you need.

```
const baseDomainWithSubPath = window.location.origin + "/" + window.location.pathname;
const baseDomain = window.location.origin;
const subDomain = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Even if you put two body tags, only one is created. This answer doesn't make sense. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Sectioning_root

Comment: @JuanMendes And that's why I clearly stated my confusion from the beginning and ending of my post. As I'm speculating there will be major issues with this one, but I'm not 100% sure to completely disregard it as I'm too lazy to research. Why you think it doesn't make sense is beyond me, simply replacing the questionnable body tags with two parent divs is plausible enough

Comment: "I'm too lazy to research". Then you shouldn't post an answer, post a comment with your thoughts. If you were really lazy, you wouldn't take the time to write an answer that you have no faith in ;)

Comment: @JuanMendes So I should post a comment of the length of my answer? Good idea. Because all I know whatever code I written there I've been doing a lot in the past, just not with the body tags. Saying I have no faith in my answer is a shot in the dark

Comment: @JuanMendes Ignoring all my other points and handpicking "I'm too lazy to research" without context is a nice fallacy you typically see on Reddit/Facebook which is the first time I've seen in this community :)

Comment: I am saying you should post a comment with a little guidance and explaining that the question needs to be refined. Your answer simply misunderstands the body element as did the OP. I'm not trying to be rude, just explaining that you are wasting your time with a long answer for a poorly worded question

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm just going to edit it to disregard body tags and using parent wrappers instead. So it would finally make at least 1% sense then

Comment: That's a much better approach, and I'll retract my downvote once it doesn't talk about two body tags :)  I can't upvote it though, since I can't understand what the OP is asking :D

Comment: @JuanMendes It's a weird scenario for sure, but sometimes you just have to take questions literally. Worked for me in the past.

Comment: thanks for this but I can't seem to get it to work. I've edited the above question to make my intentions much clearer ie change background and link according to subdomain only (not parameter)

Comment: @JuliaDavies You would have to use `window.location.pathname` for subdomain eg. example.com/MySubDomain/Foobar/Cupcakes